# Getting incorrect duplication when parsing PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

Getting to my wits end debugging what seems like a simple issue, and I'm worried that there might be something wrong with this block, that I was overlooking due to it's simplicity:

```
function sendUploads(array $files)
{
  $fileCount = count($files)-1;
  $lastFile = false;

  foreach ($files as $fileKey => $file) {

      if ($fileKey == $fileCount) {
              $file = $file . ' is the lastfile';
      }

      $uploads[] = $file;

  }     
  var_dump($uploads); 
}  

$files = array('file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4', 'file5');

sendUploads($files);
```

The expected result would be:

```
array(5) {
      [0] =>
      string(5) "file1"
      [1] =>
      string(5) "file2"
      [2] =>
      string(5) "file3"
      [3] =>
      string(5) "file4"
      [4] =>
      string(21) "file5 is the lastfile"
    }
```

But in some edge cases we're seeing this result instead:

```
array(5) {
      [0] =>
      string(5) "file1"
      [1] =>
      string(5) "file2"
      [2] =>
      string(5) "file3"
      [3] =>
      string(5) "file4"
      [4] =>
      string(21) "file5 is the lastfile"
      [5] =>
      string(21) "file5 is the lastfile"
    }
```

In all my testing I'm getting the first result, but is there a potential situation I'm missing where this function could be causing this issue?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The second example isn't possible with the code you posted. Please paste the full or actual code.

Comment: "in some edge cases"  What specifically are those cases?

Comment: can't see this being possible at all. foreach() isn't going to magically iterate one extra time just because it's having a bad hair day.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how these edge cases should be possible. But anyhow you are doing n-1 `if` comparisons for one case. Why don't you just [`end`](http://php.net/end) it and manage it on its own?

```
function sendUploads(array $files)
{
  $length = count($files);
  if ($length < 1)
    return array();

  $uploads = array();
  $last = end($files);
  for ($i=0; $i<($length-2); $i++) {
    $uploads[] = $files[$i];
  }
  $uploads[] = $last . " is the last file";

  return $uploads;
}
```

Comment: no need to modify the array at all. [end()](http://php.net/end) would do just as well.

Answer (score 0):

A variation on a theme perhaps but it originally seemed overly complicated:

```
function sendUploads( $files=array() ){
    if( empty( $files ) ) return false;
    $pop=array_pop( $files );
    $uploads=$files;
    $uploads[]=$pop.' is the last file';
    return $uploads;
}
$files = array('file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4', 'file5');
if( !empty( $files ) ) var_dump( sendUploads( $files ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you've provided would never produce the output you've included. I presume that really your code is a lot more complicated than this and you've trimmed out stuff you think is unnecessary. The problem is probably due to the fact that all arrays in PHP are associative - even when the index is an integer value. It's quite possible to have an array with keys { -1, 0, 1, "banana", 300 }. Expecting such a hash map to have an explicit order seems something of a reach.

The simplest solution I can think of (kingkero's is rather neat) would be:

```
function sendUploads(array $origfiles)
{
  $fileCount = count($files)-1;
  $lastFile = false;
  $files=array_values($origfiles);
  // or if this still causes pain sort(array_values($origfiles))

  foreach ($files as $fileKey => $file) {
      if ($fileKey == $fileCount) {
          $file = $file . ' is the lastfile';
      }
      $uploads[] = $file;

  }     
  var_dump($uploads); 
}
```